# Task.Factory.StartNew() vs. TaskEx.Run()

Tags: c#-4.0, asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library, async-ctp

Task.Factory.StartNew() basically receives an Action and returns a Task. In The Async CTP we have TaskEx.Run() which also receives an Action and returns a Task. They seem to do that same thing. Why TaskEx.Run() was introduced ?

Comment: TaskEx.Run is now Task.Run in the .NET 4.5 RTM framework
TaskEx was needed as a temporary measure

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Anders Hejlsberg talked about that briefly in an interview on [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Share). Apparently, `Task.Run` is just a shorthand for `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Its still early CTP days so we're unsure that `Task.Run` will make it int. I personally hope it won't because it's kind of redundant. :)

Comment: It did :-) I wish the documentation for this mentioned it was a shorthand for Task.Factory.StartNew - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051.aspx

Comment: This is just partially correct. [Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) talks about what to expect from `Task.Run`. Specially in the scenario where the action returns `Task<TResult>`, `Task.Factory.StartNew` would return a `Task<Task<TResult>` requiring an `Unwrap` to get the inner task where as `Task.Run` would return a `Task<TResult>` with an implicit unwrap.

Answer (score 6):

Stephen Toub covered it in [his article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx). They are the same, one being shorthand for the other.