# TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have seen that in .NET 4.5 that  `Task.Run()` is the equivalent to

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction, 
CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

But in .NET 4.0, `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach` does not exist.  Is this where `TaskEx.Run` comes in?  A comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123630/task-factory-startnew-vs-taskex-run) seems to indicate that, but no elaboration is given.  What is the equivalent in .NET 4.0 for .NET 4.5's `Task.Run`?

Comment: I'm not seeing that 4.5 `Factory.StartNew` uses `DenyChildAttach` (see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskFactory.cs)  The default `TaskFactory` used with `Task.Factory` is created with default `TaskCreationOptions.None` (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskFactory.cs) Where did you read about this?

Comment: MSDN states that Task.Run in .NET 4.5 is the equivalent of using DenyChildAttach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051.aspx aslo http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I read that backwards.  for some reason I read that `Task.Factory.StartNew` defaulted to `DenyChildAttach`.  Yes, `Task.Run()` defaults to this as opposed to `Task.Factory.StartNew(Action)`.  There is no `TaskEx` class in release bits.  The equivalent in 4.0 is to *not* use `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent`.  A task is not a child without `AttachedToParent`

Comment: That's strange because I installed the MS BCL Portability Pack using VS 2013 NuGet manager and TaskEx is in there.

Comment: Ahh, Microsoft.Bcl.Async (I assume you mean that instead of the targeting pack because it replaced the targeting pack). That's not "release bits" or part of TPL. Microsoft.Bcl.Async extends .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.0 doesn't have the `Task.Run` convenience statics and they can't *replace* the existing `Task` class--so `TaskEx` is included in Microsoft.Bcl.Async.  Other than the default `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach`, they work the same as the `Task.Run` equivalents.  I.e. `TaskEx.Run` is there because .NET 4.0 `Task.Run` doesn't exist (which are more convenient than `TaskFactory.StartNew`)

Comment: You'll notice that there are the same `TaskEx.Run` overloads as `Task.Run` overloads.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `DenyChildAttach` option not only doesn't exist in the `TaskCreationOptions` enum, it doesn't exist in the framework itself. The code that would actually **deny the attempted attachment of a child task** doesn't exist in .Net 4.0. (more in [New `TaskCreationOptions` and `TaskContinuationOptions` in .NET 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/new-taskcreationoptions-and-taskcontinuationoptions-in-net-4-5/)).

So the **exact** equivalent of `Task.Run` doesn't and can't exist in .Net 4.0. The closest thing to it would be to simply not use the `AttachedToParent` value in that enum:

```
public static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
        function, 
        CancellationToken.None, 
        TaskCreationOptions.None, 
        TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

---

A more important difference IMO is the support for `async` delegates in `Task.Run`. If you pass an `async` delegate (i.e. `Func<Task<TResult>>`) to `Factory.StartNew` you get back in return `Task<Task<TResult>>` instead of `Task<TResult>` as some would expect which is a [source of many headaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23929194/885318). The solution to that is to use the `TaskExtensions.Unwrap` extension method that "Creates a proxy `Task` that represents the asynchronous operation of a `Task<Task<T>>`":

```
public static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> function)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
        function, 
        CancellationToken.None, 
        TaskCreationOptions.None, 
        TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}
```