# How to Fill Data Grid View without being my form stop responding?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, task-parallel-library

I'm currently filling my `DataGridView` using Tasks. At first, when I fill in `dataTable`, everything is fine, but when I continue to the UI thread, my form is unresponsive for a short time.

How can I avoid this unresponsive period?

```
if (bar == null)
{
    bar = CNPR.Controls.Helper.GetWaitingBar(this);
    this.Controls.Add(bar);
}
bar.Visible = true;
bar.BringToFront();
bar.StartWaiting();
panel1.Enabled = false;
rasteTableBindingSource.DataSource = null;
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => rasteTableTableAdapter.FillBySearch(chapYarDataSet.rasteTable))
    .ContinueWith(delegate
    {
        bar.StopWaiting();
        bar.Visible = false;
        panel1.Enabled = true;
        rasteTableBindingSource.DataMember = chapYarDataSet.rasteTable.TableName;
        rasteTableBindingSource.DataSource = chapYarDataSet;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [`StartNew`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew.aspx) method with current synchronization context, so it's being run not in thread pool but on your ui. You should read the article by @StephenCleary [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) for a better understanding of your code.

You should split your logic for a data retrieval, which should be done in background, by using the [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) method, and fill the datasource in the ui context:

```
var t = Task.Run(() => rasteTableTableAdapter.FillBySearch(chapYarDataSet.rasteTable))
  .ContinueWith(delegate { /* UI logic here */ },
      TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Update: if you're using the .Net 4.0 and can't use the `Run` method, use this overload:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew({ /* Action here */ },
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Another great article is [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using .net 4 :((. Is there another solution for .net 4?

Comment: Did you read the article? There is a solution there. Updated the answer.

Comment: `TaskCreationOptions` does not have this member  `DenyChildAttach` in .net 4 :((.

Comment: Oh, yeah, forgot about that. You probably could have google it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26027328/213550

Comment: let me try your solution.